# can we have probabilistic interpretation of $L(1,( \frac{\cdot }{ p}))^{-1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, probabilistic-method

the zeta function has a probabilistic interpretation:

$$ \zeta(2)^{-1}= \prod_p  \left( 
1- \frac{1 }{p^2 }
\right) $$

can we have probabilistic interpretation of $L(1, \frac{\cdot }{ p})$ which also has an Euler product?

$$ L(1, (\frac{\cdot }{ p}))^{-1}=\prod_q  \left( 
1- (\frac{q}{ p})\frac{1 }{q}
\right)^{-1}$$

except that $1+  \frac{1 }{ q}>1 $ is not a probability.

Comment: More than a probabilistic interpretation, a really intriguing algebraic interpretation: $L(1,\chi)$ depends on the number of some reduced binary quadratic forms, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClassNumber.html